# container not stopping

Tags: command-line, permissions, docker, container

I am trying to stop a container, but it is giving me this error every time, can you help?[image: Here is the screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 0):

Just try this way no need to pass container in the cmd

**docker kill my_container**

If above doesn't work then pass the time parameter as below

**docker stop ----time=30 my_container**

When you issue a docker stop command Docker will first ask nicely for the process to stop and if it doesn't comply within 10 seconds it will forcibly kill it. If you've ever issued a docker stop and had to wait 10 seconds for the command to return you've seen this in action

The docker stop command attempts to stop a running container first by sending a SIGTERM signal to the root process (PID 1) in the container. If the process hasn't exited within the timeout period a SIGKILL signal will be sent.

Whereas a process can choose to ignore a SIGTERM, a SIGKILL goes straight to the kernel which will terminate the process. The process never even gets to see the signal.
When using docker stop the only thing you can control is the number of seconds that the Docker daemon will wait before sending the SIGKILL